# Token parser semantic action

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-bind

I have written a working token parser based on the code shown at [spirit lex example 4](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/example/lex/example4.cpp)

One of my rules looks like this

```
    set_name 
        =   (   tok.set_ >> tok.name_ >> tok.identifier )
            [
                std::cout << val("set name statement to: ") << _3 << "\n"
            ]
        ;
```

This works well.  When presented with

```
SET NAME xyz
```

it outputs as I expect

> set name statement to: xyz

Now I want to do something useful, store the name found into a class.  Working from [parser semantic examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html) I write this code

```
  class writer
    {
    public:
        void print(string const& s) const
        {
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    };

  writer w;

  ...

    set_name 
        =   (   tok.set_ >> tok.name_ >> tok.identifier )
            [
                boost::bind( &writer::print, &w, ::_3 )
            ]
        ;
```

This does not compile

```
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost/bind/bind.hpp(318) : error C2664: 'R boost::_mfi::cmf1::operator ()(const U &,A1) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'bool' to 'const std::basic_string '
1>        with
1>        [
1>            R=void,
1>            T=eCrew::rule::writer,
1>            A1=const std::string &,
1>            U=eCrew::rule::writer *
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator
1>        ]
1>        Reason: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'const std::string'
1>        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Why is the compiler complaining about a trying to convert from bool to string?  There is no bool that I can see.

Comment: In ... is w being redeclared as a bool? What happens if you use a more unique variable name for the writer?

Comment: @jon changed "w" to "the_writer".  Same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placeholder in

```
std::cout << val("set name statement to: ") << _3 << "\n"
```

refers to `boost::spirit::_3`, which is a boost.phoenix v2 placeholder. The placeholder in

```
boost::bind(&writer::print, &w, ::_3)
```

is a boost.bind placeholder (naturally).

These placeholders do **not** share the same behavior, or even refer to the same data. Phoenix placeholders of the form _*N* refer to the Nth subattribute of your parser, while bind placeholders have a different meaning:

- _1 refers to your parser's attribute as a whole
- _2 refers to the parser's context
- _3 refers to a `bool&` 'hit' parameter

The easiest solution in your case is to use `boost::phoenix::bind` instead of `boost::bind`, so that you can continue using `_3` to refer to the third subattribute of your parser instead of having to pick it out manually inside of `writer::print`.

Alternatively, only attach the semantic action to `tok.identifier` so that boost.bind's `::_1` works as you expect:

```
set_name
  = tok.set_
    >> tok.name_
    >> tok.identifier[boost::bind(&writer::print, &w, ::_1)]
;
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I will try it and get back to you.